# Python - loop through date as input into a function

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I'm learning Python and it has gone relatively well so far. However I have run into an obstacle.

I have a CSV file (336 rows and 2657 columns) which contains daily data of spot rates of different instruments of different maturities:

[image]

I also have a function called `importdata`, which imports the data for one instrument, say all the 3M USD, at one one date, say on 03/09/2021 (m/d/y). name is the instrument (so 3M USD):

```
def importdata (fileloc, date, name, max_maturity=None):
    'Imports data from a given location, date and name'
    data = pd.read_csv(fileloc) # file location 
    result = data[ (data['date']) == date] # getting the date of the curve
    data =  result.loc[:, result.columns.str.startswith(name)] # getting the curve wanted at the date
    data = data.T # Transposing the data
    data = data.reset_index()
    data.columns = ['maturity','spot rate'] # renaming columns
    data['maturity'] = data.maturity.str.rsplit(n=1).str[-1]
    if max_maturity:
        data = data.iloc[:data.loc[data.maturity.str.contains(max_maturity,na=False)].index[0]+1]
    return data
```

An example output of `importdata` of all the 3M USD instruments at the 9th March 2021:

```
        maturity
0   1Y  0.188
1   2Y  0.245
2   3Y  0.431
3   4Y  0.672
4   5Y  0.892
5   6Y  1.083
6   7Y  1.2429999999999999
7   8Y  1.369
8   9Y  1.474
9   10Y 1.561
10  12Y 1.699
11  15Y 1.8259999999999998
12  20Y 1.9240000000000002
13  25Y 1.96
14  30Y 1.975
```

This dataframe would then be used as an input into another function which takes the above data and calculates forward rates. I want to progress this further by being able to run `importdate` for each date in one go by looping over the dates.   So far, `importdata` I would have to change the dates manually, and as there are 2657 dates, this would take a long time.

I know I have to create a for loop to loop over the dates, but I am not sure how to put it as as input to `importdata` so that it can run for all the dates.

```
for dt in all_data['date']: 
    print (dt)
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the rows of a DataFrame using iterrows().

```
for dt in all_data['date'].iterrows():
    importdata(fileloc, dt, name)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, when I run your code it just prints out the date, unless I've missed out on something.

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted your questions, I have changed my answer.